# How to display a random Flutter map?

Tags: flutter, dart, fluttermap

I am trying to display a random Flutter map using the flutter_maps package. When I was creating this, I couldn't find the 'layers' option under the map options. If I type layers I got an error "Parameter named 'layers' is not defined."

I have added all the required dependencies. How to solve this?

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart' as LatLng;
```

```
Container(                         //container 1
          height: 800,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: FlutterMap(
            options: MapOptions(
              center: LatLng.LatLng(23.77176, 90.399452),
              zoom: 8,
            ),
            ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `layers` option is not available in the `MapOptions` class of the `flutter_map` package. Instead, you can add one or more layers to the map using the `children` property of the `FlutterMap` widget:

```
return FlutterMap(
    options: MapOptions(
        center: LatLng(51.509364, -0.128928),
        zoom: 9.2,
    ),
    nonRotatedChildren: [
        AttributionWidget.defaultWidget(
            source: 'OpenStreetMap contributors',
            onSourceTapped: null,
        ),
    ],
    children: [
        TileLayer(
            urlTemplate: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            userAgentPackageName: 'com.example.app',
        ),
    ],
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Tried using layers after options. But I couldn't use layers[], if I type layers I get the below error "The named parameter 'layers' isn't defined." Do I need additional permission to use the layer option?

Comment: @Divya I have updated the code in my answer. Try this way and let me know if it works!

Comment: Wow! Thanks, it works. May I know why the layer option is not working for me?

Comment: @Divya I'm glad that it works! About the layer option, I don't know exactly. But I suspect the plugin author has removed the layer option in one of the recent versions.